# Storing an empty integer into database

Tags: c#

There! I Want to know how to store null a value in a column which is accepting int data type and the data is pushed from the asp.net c# textbox

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_leader2_mob", txtphno);
```

Comment: can you show what did you try to find the solution for your problem? Did you do some research? If yes, pls include them in the post.

Comment: I am doing a project, in that I created a form for the user, I have a textbox which is accepting the integer value, it's an optional one so if the user didn't enter the data still the data's must be entered into the database but I don't know how to check whether the textbox is having value or not?